# Python - TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, requests

Я хочу сделать скрипт для VkMix который будет сам выполнять задания, сначала надо авторизироваться. Авторизация проходит через запрос ссылки. В общем, я получил ответ в виде JSON. Оттуда мне надо достать параметр link. Но при добавлении его в переменную "task" Python жалуется на Python - TypeError: string indices must be integers.

Что я делаю не так?

```
import requests
import json

req = requests.get("http://vkmix.com/i/?act=auth_by_like&network=vk&identity=id")
data = req.json()


jsonreq = json.dumps(data)

task = json.loads(jsonreq['link'])
```

Вывод `print(data)`:

```
{'response': {'photo': 'photo-183961583_457318846', 'link': 'vk.com/photo-1*39*1583_45*31*846'}}
```

Comment: зачем делаешь json.loads?

Comment: `json()` возвращает словарь, к данным в нем обращайтесь просто через `data['link']`, никаких дополнительных dumps/loads не нужно.

Comment: @АлександрКотовский что бы добавить значение "link" в переменную task

Comment: @insolor может это я что то не так делаю, не знаю. Получается убрал dump/loads. Оставил data["link"]. Теперь жалуется на: KeyError: 'link' . Если туплю, извини XD

Comment: Сделайте print(data) и добавьте в вопрос то что выведет

Comment: @insolor {'response': {'photo': 'photo-183961583_457318846', 'link': 'http://vk.com/photo-1*39*1583_45*31*846'}}

В вопрос в вопрос добавить в смысле? Не совсем понял

Comment: Добавить в вопрос - нажать "править" под вопросом, вставить текст, сохранить. В вашем случае нужно делать `data['response']['link']`

Comment: @insolor , data['response']['link'] заработал. Спасибо <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `.json()` возвращает полученный json в виде python объекта (например, словаря или списка). Вы еще зачем-то пытаетесь этот объект преобразовать обратно в json строку, а потом обратно в python объект. Просто обращайтесь к возвращенным данным по ключу:

```
import requests
import json

req = requests.get("http://vkmix.com/i/?act=auth_by_like&network=vk&identity=id")
data = req.json()
task = data['response']['link']  # с учетом вида полученного словаря из комментария
```